# Salesforce Marketing cloud JB Check if record exists in DE

Tags: salesforce-marketing-cloud

In one of our clients, in the lower crm salesforce environments (DEV and TEST) there exists real data. This is not correct and data should be masked. We are looking in it but will take time due to different team maintain different part of ecosystem.

Salesforce CRM call JB using Api event entry source. In the request message , we have tag called as "Enviroment" --> Possible values (PROD,TEST)

We have a DE in SFMC called TestEmail which contain all internal tester's email address

We want in Journey , if the Enviroment == TEST, the journey should check if recipient email address exists in TestEmail DE. If it exist, then sent the email

If it doesn't then stop.

Possible options I tried and don't think will work in our situation

1. Custom decision split
2. Using exit criteria
3. Adding RaiseError to email ampscript.

Except these is there any clean way to achieve it.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the solution you mentioned is the only solution to test the journey.

The best solution would be to solve this at the source, meaning to spend the effort to mask the data in your test and dev environment. In general I believe that is the way to go, since you want to avoid sending any test messages to real clients. The simplest way to mask the data would be to use different subscriber keys and email adreses.